# Rendering sign-in view giving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

**Controller code**

class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController

```
def sign_in
    @user=User.new
end

def login
    username_or_email=params[:user][:username]
    password=params[:user][:password]

    #check for the username or email
    if username_or_email.rindex('@')
        email=username_or_email
    else
        email=username_or_email
    end

    if User.authenticate(email,password)
      flash[:notice] = 'Welcome.'
      redirect_to :root
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Unknown user. Please check your username and password.'
      render "sign_in"
    end
```

**Sign-in view Code**

```
<p>Sign In</p>
<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => sign_in_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'username or email:' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'password:' %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Sign In' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Clear Form', :type => 'reset' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Error:-
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty when I am rendering Sign_In form after the user is not authorised.

Comment: What do you mean by "problem"? Share that exact problem or error.

Comment: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: It is **nil** not **null**.